# Gradle build: Could not create an instance of Tooling API

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip'.

I tried the following based on other answers from SO:

1. Reinstalled gradle (using brew)
2. Removed Android studio and everything associated (except the SDK). Including the caches, logs.
3. Manually downloaded the gradle-2.6 zip and placed it inside .gradle/wrapper/dists
4. I even tried deleting a bunch of files from the plugins directory. Didn't work.

From my event log :

```
14:14:19 Throwable: Null child action in group Toolbar Run Actions () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GradleKiller.KillGradle
14:14:20 Gradle sync started
14:14:21 Gradle sync failed: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip'.
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
14:14:22 Throwable: Null child action in group Toolbar Run Actions () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GradleKiller.KillGradle
14:14:22 Unregistered VCS root detected
     The directory /Users/anuj/projects/makerville/android is under Git, but is not registered in the Settings.
     Add root  Configure  Ignore
14:14:27 Throwable: Null child action in group Toolbar Run Actions () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GradleKiller.KillGradle
14:14:32 Throwable: Null child action in group Toolbar Run Actions () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GradleKiller.KillGradle
```

Other details :

Android Studio 1.3.1
JRE 1.6.0

build.gradle looks like

```
14:14:19 Throwable: Null child action in group Toolbar Run Actions () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GradleKiller.KillGradle
14:14:20 Gradle sync started
14:14:21 Gradle sync failed: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.6-all.zip'.
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
14:14:22 Throwable: Null child action in group Toolbar Run Actions () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GradleKiller.KillGradle
14:14:22 Unregistered VCS root detected
     The directory /Users/anuj/projects/makerville/android is under Git, but is not registered in the Settings.
     Add root  Configure  Ignore
14:14:27 Throwable: Null child action in group Toolbar Run Actions () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GradleKiller.KillGradle
14:14:32 Throwable: Null child action in group Toolbar Run Actions () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GradleKiller.KillGradle
14:14:37 Throwable: Null child action in group Toolbar Run Actions () of class class com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DefaultActionGroup, id=GradleKiller.KillGradle
```

Comment: Try to use gradle 2.5 and jdk 7

Comment: Did. Same issue. (2.4 and 7)

Comment: I have the same problem with gradle killer plugin(android studio 1.5.1)

Comment: update your gradle dependancy